# CXF rest client not working with JAXRSServerFactoryBean

Tags: java, rest, client, cxf

I want to create a rest client using CXF. The following code throws exceptions

```
JAXRSServerFactoryBean sf = new JAXRSServerFactoryBean();
        sf.setResourceClasses(Blogger.class);
        sf.getInInterceptors().add(new LoggingInInterceptor());
        sf.getOutInterceptors().add(new LoggingOutInterceptor());
        sf.setAddress("http://myservice");
        Map<Object, Object> mappings = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
        mappings.put("xml", "application/xml");
        mappings.put("json", "application/json");
        sf.setExtensionMappings(mappings);
        sf.create();
```

The exception I got is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/WebApplicationException
    at com.test.LoggingTest.main(LoggingTest.java:26)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `javax.ws.rs` API .jar is missing on the classpath. Correct the settings of your dependency management tool or add it manually to the classpath. From the [Apache CXF documentation](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs.html#JAX-RS-MigratingfromJAXRS1.1to2.0):

- 2.7 requires the JSR-339 api (JAX-RS 2.0) : `javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api/m10`
- 2.6 and older uses JSR-311 api (JAX-RS 1.0)

Comment: glad you got it working, be so kind as to accept the answer that gave the best advice (:

Comment: I had org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.JAXRSClientFactoryBean.create() threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/client/ClientException when (transitevely from another dependency) using version 2.0.1 of javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api instead of 2.0-m10 for CXF 2.7.16.  Forcing the use of version 2.0-m10 fixed it for me.

Answer (score 3):

have you included `jsr311-api-1.1.jar` to your classpath? If you use maven this might help you (JAS-RS 1.1)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

or JAX-RS 2.0 version

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
```